# Load an image from URL as base64 string

Tags: c#, url, xamarin, base64

I am trying to load an image as a base 64 string so that i can show it in a html like this:

```
 <html><body><img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,/></img></body></html>
```

Heres my code so far, but it does not really work:

```
   public async static Task<string> getImage(string url)
   {
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
   request.Accept = "data:image/jpg;charset=base64";
   request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pw);
   using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)(await Task<WebResponse>.Factory.FromAsync(request.BeginGetResponse, request.EndGetResponse, null)))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            return sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
```

I tried using this method i found elsewhere to encode the return-String as base64, but when placing it in a html the image just shows the typical placeholder.

```
    public static string Base64Encode(string plainText)
    {
        var plainTextBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        return System.Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);
    }
```

EDIT:

Here is how the html looks: 
[image]

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do, I'm afraid. What is the URL to? The image? Is the idea that you're creating the HTML, and want to embed the data from another URL inside it? If so, I'd fetch that data without using base64 or text at all...

Comment: Yes the url leads to the image and ends with .jpg. Theres a good reason for doing things this way, but its really complex and i do not think it would add to my question.

Comment: Why? The advantage of a base64 string is that you don't have to load the image over HTTP. If you loading it over HTTP anyway then you loose the only advantage of using base64 encoding. Just put the URL in the src.

Comment: @Liam i cannot do that, the html gets displayed in a xamarin forms webview which does not support authentification, so thats why i need to manually load the images.

Comment: Before I write an answer, is there any reason you're not using `HttpClient` here, but instead using the old `BeginGetResponse`, `EndGetResponse`?

Comment: @JonSkeet im afraid the only reason is my inexperience ergo me not knowing better :)

Comment: I am having the same issue, did you get this working?

Comment: @AntRadha yep, Jon Skeets answer did it for me

Answer (score 33, accepted):

It seems to me that you need to separate the base64 part, which is only needed in your HTML, from fetching the data from the response. Just fetch the data from the URL as binary data and convert that to base64. Using `HttpClient` makes this simple:

```
public async static Task<string> GetImageAsBase64Url(string url)
{
    var credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pw);
    using (var handler = new HttpClientHandler { Credentials = credentials })
    using (var client = new HttpClient(handler))
    {
        var bytes = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
        return "image/jpeg;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
    }
}
```

This assumes the image always *will* be a JPEG. If it could sometimes be a different content type, you may well want to fetch the response as an `HttpResponse` and use that to propagate the content type.

I suspect you may want to add caching here as well :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but sadly, inputting the return string into the html string like i showed in my question still only results in the placeholder being shown

Comment: @StarterPack: So you need to diagnose what's going wrong. Look at the bytes obtained in the method - do they look appropriate for your image? Basically, trace the whole process through. I can't help you any more without knowing what's going on.

Comment: I tried decoding the base64 string on here http://www.opinionatedgeek.com/dotnet/tools/base64decode/ but it just tells me:      "The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or an illegal character among the padding characters. " So apparently the output is broken, do you have any other idea what i could try?

Comment: Well if you tried decoding the result *including the image/jpeg;base64," part then no, that wouldn't work... It's very hard to help you with so little information. We don't know what binary data you got back, what your HTML ended up like, etc.

Comment: No, i did not include the "image/jpeg" etc. The bytearray i get back is of size [36623], so i dont know how to show it to you. When i did take a look though, i realized that all entries are between 0-255 so that seems like a good result at first.

Comment: What's the url @StarterPack? If you go to that url does it return a valid image?

Comment: @StarterPack: My guess is that you didn't copy all of the base64 string then. I haven't seen `Convert.ToBase64String` fail.

Comment: I did copy all of it and right now i am using https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Patern_test.jpg as a test image. I also updated the original question with how the html looks. EDIT: Actually i didnt copy all of it since the visual studio text visualizer has a max size, sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

This solution works in.NET Core 3.1

```
  public static async Task<string> ImageUrlToBase64(string imageUrl)
  {
     using var httClient = new HttpClient();
     var imageBytes = await httClient.GetByteArrayAsync(imageUrl);                
     return Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
  }

var encodedBase64 = WebUtility.UrlEncode(await ImageUrlToBase64(ImageUrl));
```

If you have JS in front-end, use the following code:

```
var base64String = 'data:image/png;base64,' + encodedBase64;
$("#photo").attr('src', base64String);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        using (Stream stream = await client.GetStreamAsync(uri))
                        {
                            if (stream == null)
                                return (Picture)null;
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[16384];
                            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                            {
                                while (true)
                                {
                                    int num = await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, cancellation);
                                    int read;
                                    if ((read = num) > 0)
                                        ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
                                    else
                                        break;
                                }
                                imageData = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
                            }
                            buffer = (byte[])null;
                        } 
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                         
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score -2):

You must first get the image from disk, then convert it to byte[] and then again to base64.

```
    public string ImageToBase64(Image image, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format)
    {
      using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
      {
    // Convert Image to byte[]
    image.Save(ms, format);
    byte[] imageBytes = ms.ToArray();

    // Convert byte[] to Base64 String
    string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(imageBytes);
    return base64String;
  }
}
```

Comment: No, there's no need to save it to disk first.

Comment: @JonSkeet I didn't say that, re-read my answer, I'm talking about reading

Comment: Then I suggest you reread the question - the image isn't *on* disk on the OP's machine. And there's certainly no need to use an `Image` here.